# Drop down menu is not showing up

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Drop down menu is not showing up... I've done all that is required but, I don't know still its not showing up.

This is my css:

```
/* hbg */
 .hbg {
    background:url('images/hbg_bg.png') repeat-x 50% top;
    margin-bottom:32px;
    text-align: center;
}
.hbg_resize {
    padding-left:0;
    width:930px;
    height:283px;
    border-bottom:8px solid #272f33;
}
.hbg .hbg_r {
    margin-left:30px !important;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
    width:420px;
    color:#fff;
}
.hbg img.hbgimg {
    padding-top:28px;
    float:right;
}
.hbg h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:16px 0 0 0;
    font:bold 24px/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.hbg .nav_menu ul {
    margin:0 12px 0 0;
    padding:0 20px;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    list-style:none;
    height:57px;
    background-color:#272f33;
}
.hbg .nav_menu ul li {
    padding:15px 1px;
    float:left;
    height:27px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.hbg .nav_menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px 12px 0;
    color:#9fa0a0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hbg .nav_menu ul li a:hover, .hbg .nav_menu ul li.active a {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:4px solid #1872a6;
}
/*Drop down menu start*/

/*Initialize*/
 ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
 ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
 ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
 ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
/*Drop down menu ends*/
```

And this is the HTML code for the above given css code:

```
<div class="hbg">
    <div class="hbg_resize">
        <div class="nav_menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="Homenew.aspx">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Dash board</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>Sub Menu</li>
                        <li>Web Development</li>
                        <li>Illustrations</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Alerts</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sites</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="images/hbg_img.jpg" width="446" height="241" alt="pix" class="hbgimg" />
        <div class="hbg_r">
             <h2 style="color: #FFFFFF">&nbsp;</h2>GeEms
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><strong style="color: #FFFFFF">GeEms Emonitoring Live Powered by Teamsustain LTD<br/>
        </strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems you have copy pasted this from some other sites. You don't have definition of most of the css class used in your html like hbg, hbgimg etc. Check again your reference there might be specific css file source which you need to add to make it work.

Comment: @NitinAgrawal, I can see these classes inside css...

Comment: My bad...I think I scrolled your big css and did not noticed that they were defined on top. Any way do you have working prototype to show desired behaviour?

Comment: @NitinAgrawal Please scroll up and check you can see all the css class for hbg, hbgimg etc...

Comment: @Jilu Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/330/  ?

Comment: Yes exactly... Thank you... I found that my css file was not reaching up to the line... So just repositioned the css file in the page and finally made it work...

Comment: @KK, it's good that you've reached the final goal, but you didn't solve the problem of the issue. You've added several new rules that does the trick, but still CSS is incorrect with it's `id` and `class` selectors.

Comment: @WhiteAngel Agreed! But in the last comment, Jilu mentioned that the cause of the issue is found and it finally worked. I just showed the way in which it can be done. Rest of the changes/modification depends on Jilu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `class` and `id` inside your CSS selectors for `menu` class.
This code `ul#menu` means that you are trying to access `<ul id='menu'>` where you got defined `<ul class='menu'>`

You got 2 choices:

1. Add id to your menu item like this: `<ul class="menu" id="menu">`. Here's JSBin for this: http://jsbin.com/janojubafeja/2/edit
2. Change all instances of `#menu` to `.menu` inside your CSS file

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @WhiteAngel. I've tried both the ways but still no luck. I can't even see any difference...

Comment: @Jilu, Somehow I gave you link to incorrect JSBin - I've updated it in my post: http://jsbin.com/janojubafeja/2/edit . Try it (rev. 2).